# Calling Objective-C init method in Swift not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, coordinates, utm

I am trying to use this API to convert coordinates: https://github.com/palmerc/GeodeticUTMConverter

It has an Objective-C class header called "GeodeticUTMConverter.h" which includes:

```
@interface GeodeticUTMConverter : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) UTMDatum utmDatum;

+ (CLLocationCoordinate2D)UTMCoordinatesToLatitudeAndLongitude:(UTMCoordinates)UTMCoordinates;
+ (UTMCoordinates)latitudeAndLongitudeToUTMCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)latitudeAndLongitudeCoordinates;

- (id)initWithDatum:(UTMDatum)datum;

- (CLLocationCoordinate2D)UTMCoordinatesToLatitudeAndLongitude:(UTMCoordinates)UTMCoordinates;
- (UTMCoordinates)latitudeAndLongitudeToUTMCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)latitudeAndLongitudeCoordinates;
@end
```

And an implementation "GeodeticUTMConverter.m":

```
@implementation GeodeticUTMConverter

+ (CLLocationCoordinate2D)UTMCoordinatesToLatitudeAndLongitude:(UTMCoordinates)UTMCoordinates
{
    GeodeticUTMConverter *utmConverter = [[GeodeticUTMConverter alloc] init];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D latLong = [utmConverter UTMCoordinatesToLatitudeAndLongitude:UTMCoordinates];
    return latLong;
}

+ (UTMCoordinates)latitudeAndLongitudeToUTMCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)latitudeAndLongitudeCoordinates
{
    GeodeticUTMConverter *utmConverter = [[self alloc] init];
    UTMCoordinates utmCoordinates = [utmConverter latitudeAndLongitudeToUTMCoordinates:latitudeAndLongitudeCoordinates];
    return utmCoordinates;
}



- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        UTMDouble equitorialRadius = 6378137;
        UTMDouble polarRadius = 6356752.3142;
        UTMDatum wgs84datum = UTMDatumMake(equitorialRadius, polarRadius);

        _utmDatum = wgs84datum;

        _utmScaleFactor = 0.9996;
    }

    return self;
}
```

I am trying to use the two conversion functions in my swift code, so I try to create an instance of it in swift using:

```
var instance = GeodeticUTMConverter()
```

But I get a "Use of unresolved identifier" error. I have looked at a lot of SO posts to ensure that my bridging header is correct. It is listed properly in my build settings and I use the name of the objective C header file in the following way:

```
#import "GeodeticUTMConverter.h"
```

All files are in the same folder as well so I feel like I must be doing something wrong with my Swift syntax. While I'm on the subject, does anyone know how I would make a "UTMCoordinates" variable in swift? It has a typedef in the GeodeticUTMConverter.h file:

```
typedef double UTMDouble;
typedef unsigned int UTMGridZone;

typedef enum {
    kUTMHemisphereNorthern,
    kUTMHemisphereSouthern
} UTMHemisphere;

typedef struct {
    UTMDouble northing;
    UTMDouble easting;
    UTMGridZone gridZone;
    UTMHemisphere hemisphere;
} UTMCoordinates;

typedef struct {
    UTMDouble equitorialRadius;
    UTMDouble polarRadius;
} UTMDatum;
```

Comment: Nothing's wrong with your swift syntax. `let converter = GeodeticUTMConverter()` should get you a converter instance. And to get a `UTMCoordinates` instance use: 
`let coordinates = UTMCoordinates(northing: 0, easting: 0, gridZone: 0, hemisphere: UTMHemisphere(rawValue: 0))` Just tested this in a clean setup.